# Error: 2136 when trying to call document class variables and methods inside symbol

Tags: class, flash, actionscript, document

thank you for viewing my issue. I was just trying in the code you see below to get access of public variables and methods working, and now my .swf preview gives me Error 2136 stating the .swf contains invalid data and I'm unable to find a working solution or a fix on my own. Help is much appreciated thanks.

The below code is my Symbol Definition for an object that spawns and plummets across the screen like a meteor.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import PublicVariables;

var pubVars:PublicVariables = new PublicVariables();


this.x = pubVars.randomValue(0, 550); //set x position to random value





    if (this.x < 275) //determine whether to make the direction of motion left or right
    {
        var direction:Boolean = false;
        trace("go right")
    }
    else
    {
        direction = true;
        trace("go left")
    }



this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);

function animate (evt:Event) :void {

switch (direction)
{
    case direction=true: //go left {    
    {       
    this.x -= pubVars.xSpeed;
    break;
    }
    case direction=false: //go right
    {
        this.x += pubVars.xSpeed;
        break;
    }
}
    this.y += pubVars.ySpeed;


}
```

Comment: Probably your `switch` statement,  its not right.  do:   `case true:`  and `case false:`   instead of `case direction=true` .  Also, there should be no curly braces `{` in yoru case statements

Comment: Show the code of your `PublicVariables`

Comment: Also, you're declaring your direction var inside an if statement, which makes it only exist in that context, move the `var direction:Boolean` out of the if statement so it can be accessed by all your code.